# Airflow CeleryExecutor - 'int' object has no attribute 'startswith' in Celery

Tags: python, celery, airflow, airflow-scheduler, directed-acyclic-graphs

Airflow 2.0 is queuing but not launching tasks in my dev environment.

DAG and Pool settings are valid, but all tasks in each dag are `queued` when I trigger them, and are never running.

When typing `airflow celery worker`, I've got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 40, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 48, in command
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 92, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/celery_command.py", line 188, in worker
    _run_worker(options=options, skip_serve_logs=skip_serve_logs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/celery_command.py", line 94, in _run_worker
    celery_app.worker_main(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 365, in worker_main
    return instantiate(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 283, in execute_from_commandline
    self.maybe_patch_concurrency(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 315, in maybe_patch_concurrency
    maybe_patch_concurrency(argv, *pool_option)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/__init__.py", line 143, in maybe_patch_concurrency
    pool = _find_option_with_arg(argv, short_opts, long_opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/__init__.py", line 95, in _find_option_with_arg
    if arg.startswith('-'):
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

In my staging, prod environment there are no issues with running tasks as well as if I check `airflow celery worker`. It will start or warn me that it is already running (as expected).

There are no difference between envs, but I guess that the problem occurred after most-recent deploy on server.

As I can see, celery received the wrong argument:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

But how to trace which params Airflow trying to pass to celery?
I have no Idea how to debug this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved by upgrading celery to It's latest version from `4.4.2` to `5.1.2`.

Seems like version `4.4.2` (which is a one of airflow deps) had a bug with arguments.

If there are any other suggestions how to solve this issue, feel free to mention them here.

Comment: I get an `ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts. flower 0.9.7 requires celery<5.0.0,>=4.3.0; python_version >= "3.7", but you have celery 5.1.2 which is incompatible.

Answer (score 2):

For airflow 2.1.0+, you need celery 5.1.2+

Documentation is here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-celery/stable/index.html#pip-requirements which explains the need for celery 5.1.2+

Comment: I get this error: flower 0.9.7 requires celery<5.0.0,>=4.3.0; python_version >= "3.7", but you have celery 5.1.2 which is incompatible.

Comment: and eventually from the log: `pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (celery 5.1.2 (/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages), Requirement.parse('celery<5.0.0,>=4.3.0; python_version >= "3.7"'))`